# Simpler way to write this if-else with nested foreach

Tags: php, html, if-statement, foreach, dry

I have a PHP structure that looks like this:

```
<?php if(isset($section->subsection)): ?>
    <?php foreach ($section->subsection as $subsection) : ?>
        <div class="subsection">
            <h3><?= $subsection->category ?></h3>
            <div class="item-list">
                <?php foreach ($subsection->item as $item) : ?>
                    <div class="item">
                        <span class="item-aside"><?php echo $item->aside; ?></span>
                        <h4 class="item-name"><?php echo $item->name; ?></h4>
                        <p class="item-desc"><?php echo $item->description; ?></p>
                    </div>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <div class="item-list">
        <?php foreach ($section->item as $item) : ?>
            <div class="item">
                <span class="item-aside"><?php echo $item->aside; ?></span>
                <h4 class="item-name"><?php echo $item->name; ?></h4>
                <p class="item-desc"><?php echo $item->description; ?></p>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

As you can see a part of this code is essentially duplicated, everything inside the `<div class="item-list">` is almost exactly the same but written in two separate places. Is there a simpler way this control structure can be written following DRY principles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've figured it out by combining @mike.k's function principle and @Alvin's syntax:

```
<?php function show_items($section){
    echo "<div class='item-list'>";
    foreach ($section->item as $item) {
        echo "<div class='item'>
                <span class='item-aside font-italic'>" . $item->aside . "</span>
                <h4 class='item-name'>" . $item->name . "</h4>
                <p class='item-desc'> " . $item->description . "</p>
            </div>";
    }
    echo "</div>";
}; ?>
<?php if(isset($section->subsection)): ?>
    <?php foreach ($section->subsection as $section) : ?>
        <div class="subsection">
            <h3 class="text-center my-3"><?= $section->category ?></h3>
            <?php show_items($section); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <?php show_items($section); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I may have some syntax *not quite right* because I never write PHP in this syntax, but you should get the idea -- function does the work, call it with the list of items you need each time.

```
<?php
function show_items($items) {
    echo '<div class="item-list">';
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        echo '
        <div class="item">
            <span class="item-aside">' . htmlentities($item->aside) . '</span>
            <h4 class="item-name">' . htmlentities($item->name) . '</h4>
            <p class="item-desc">' . htmlentities($item->description) . '</p>
        </div>';
    echo "</div>\n";
}
?>

<?php if(isset($section->subsection)): ?>
    <?php foreach ($section->subsection as $subsection) : ?>
        <div class="subsection">
            <h3><?= $subsection->category ?></h3>
            <?php show_items($subsection->item); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <?php show_items($section->item); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that syntax only works for control structures (if, while, for, foreach, and switch), but this is essentially what I was already thinking. I'll have to combine this with [@AlvinChing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51182355/3053568)'s syntax

Comment: Thanks @Aender, I revised it based on your comments

Answer (score 1):

I might not be able to give the most optimized code but this structure of code will really help you. Instead of applying `<?php .... ?>` per line, try this..

```
<?php 
  if(isset($section->subsection)){
    foreach ($section->subsection as $subsection) {
      echo "
      <div class='subsection'>
        <h3>" . $subsection->category . "</h3>
        <div class='item-list'>";
        foreach ($subsection->item as $item) {
          echo "
          <div class='item'>
            <span class='item-aside'>" . $item->aside . "</span>
            <h4 class='item-name'>" . $item->name . "</h4>
            <p class='item-desc'>" . $item->description . "</p>
          </div>";
        }
        echo "</div></div>";

    }
  }else{
    echo "<div class='item-list'>";
       foreach ($section->item as $item) {
         echo "
         <div class='item'>
           <span class='item-aside'>" . $item->aside . "</span>
           <h4 class='item-name'>" . $item->name . "</h4>
           <p class='item-desc'> " . $item->description . "</p>
         </div>";
      }
       echo "</div>";
  }
?>
```

You could minified the code by removing the new lines. I just thought it would be more readable if I put some new lines inside the echo. :D

Comment: Yeah, I think I'm going to have to use this syntax at least partially in a function that will be called.

Comment: Thanks! Please give it an upvote if its helpful. So that it could still help other users. :)

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is write a function that executes a `foreach` loop on an iterable that is passed to the function via an argument, which places each item into an array, and then returns the array. Now you'd be able to access each item as an array element. For instance...

```
$itemArr = outputArr(array)
$itemArr[0]
```

You get the idea!

Comment: But he still needs a `for` loop to loop through the data and output it, twice.

Comment: @Mehdi no, he wouldn't he saves the output of the function to a variable (`$itemArr`) and then references items in that array (`$itemArr[0]`, ..., `$itemArr[22]`, etc) wherever he needs to...

Comment: But what if the item's count is dynamic?

Comment: @Mehdi is the count dynamic tho? if that's the case, you could reference items like `$itemArr[count($itemArr)]`, even tho it wouldn't get u very far. u could write other code in the function or elsewhere to deal with that without writing more loops...